# ANR in com.google.android.apps.messaging

Tags: android

Got the following error in Google Play prelaunch report:

```
ANR in com.google.android.apps.messaging;PID: 15781;Broadcast of Intent 
{ act=android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED flg=0x5000010 cmp=com.google.android.apps.messaging/com.google.apps.tiktok.account.data.device.DeviceAccountsChangedReceiver_Receiver };
```

What is it? How to test this?